# How can i pass variables to event handler function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I pass `modalData` variable to `clickOutsideModalHandler()` event handler without getting any errors?

```
$('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    var modalData = {
        confirmText: $(this).data('confirm-text'),
        cancelText: $(this).data('cancel-text'),
        confirmMessage: $(this).data('confirm-message')
    };

    $(document).click(clickOutsideModalHandler);

});

$('.modal').on('hide.bs.modal', function() {
    $(document).unbind('click', clickOutsideModalHandler);
});

function clickOutsideModalHandler() {
    var obj = $(".modal-content");

    if (!obj.is(event.target) && !obj.has(event.target).length) {
        var formFieldset = obj.find("form").find("fieldset").attr("disabled");
        if(formFieldset !== "disabled") {
            yii.confirm("send form?", function(){
                obj.find("form").submit();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

[`unbind`](https://api.jquery.com/unbind/) is deprecated (you should use [`off`](https://api.jquery.com/off/) instead).

And using `event` in your `clickOutsideModalHandler` relies also on a deprecated feature [Window.event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event), you should use the event passed as argument to the callback.

The [`on`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) function has this signature `.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )`

> `data`
> Type: Anything
> Data to be passed to the handler in event.data when an event is triggered.

So you can set the data to be passed with the event using the `data` parameter:

```js
$('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
  var modalData = {
    confirmText: 'test',
    cancelText: 'test',
    confirmMessage: 'test',
  };
  $(document).on('click', modalData, clickOutsideModalHandler);
});

$('.modal').on('hide.bs.modal', function() {
  $(document).off('click', clickOutsideModalHandler);
});

function clickOutsideModalHandler(event) {
  // access the data using the data property of the event object
  console.dir(event.data);

  // rest of you code
}

// that part is just here to make the snippet functional
$('.modal').trigger('shown.bs.modal')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="modal">modal</div>
<div>some other content</div>
```

Comment: Why to answr this question even after making this as duplicate?

Comment: @Nitheesh I answered it and was in parallel searching for a duplicate. I found a matching duplicate after I answered it. And I furthermore pointed out some other problems in the original code. I especially answered it because I haven't found a duplicate at the time you have written your answer, and due to the problems in your answers, and given that jquery already provides an API to pass data I wrote that answer to show one that is, in my opinion, a better solution.